# SQL Server 2012, dúvidas

Tags: sql-server, join

Com base na tabela anexada, vocês poderiam me dizer se a resolução do exercício abaixo está correta?

> Mostre os pedidos que possuem itens que foram vendidos com desconto (desconto ocorre quando o preço de venda – ITE_PrecoUnitario  - é menor que o preço de “tabela” – PRO_Preco).

Minha resolução:

```
select p.ped_numero, ite_precounitario, pro_preco
from pedido p, item i, produto pr
where p.ped_numero = i.ped_numero 
and i.pro_codigo = pr.pro_codigo
and ite_precounitario < pro_preco
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está, mas eu colocaria todos os prefixos pra evitar ambiguidades:

```
select p.ped_numero, i.ite_precounitario, pr.pro_preco
from pedido p, item i, produto pr
where p.ped_numero = i.ped_numero 
and i.pro_codigo = pr.pro_codigo
and i.ite_precounitario < pr.pro_preco
```

Passaria também para a sintaxe ANSI, que é mais legível:

```
select p.ped_numero, i.ite_precounitario, pr.pro_preco
from pedido p
    inner join item i on p.ped_numero = i.ped_numero 
    inner join produto pr on i.pro_codigo = pr.pro_codigo
where i.ite_precounitario < pr.pro_preco
```